# Sharing a wallet with a friend

Tags: wallet

How can I share my bitcoin wallet with my family members? Such that if my grandmother spends one btc one day, I see that reflected on my computer, etc.

This is also a great safety mechanism, in case one of our family member's hard drive crashes, the other members will still have the wallet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for something technically straight-forward, I suggest using an "e-wallet" and giving your partner access to the wallet account.

Review these links:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Browser-based_wallet

And here are several e-wallet's listed:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Category:EWallets

Comment: I'm looking for a way without third party help. I just want to manipulate wallets on the different local computers. Any ideas? For instance, why does the Bitcoin software only support the creation and manipulation of a single wallet? That's a bummer.

Comment: Because there's a lot of risk if a wallet.dat file is open by multiple clients... bad things could happen. There's been talk of one file being "primary" or one set of private / public keys on a system being the "primary" and propagating that out, but that's a bit advanced. Check out this answer on running multiple clients to access the same file: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/490/can-i-use-my-wallet-on-different-computers

Answer (score 3):

Electrum is a client that uses "deterministic keys", and thus multiple installations of the same wallet seed are supported.

- http://ecdsa.org/electrum
- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Electrum

(The only exception is if you import keys generated externally, an Electrum wallet those transactions are exclusive to the wallet in which they are imported.)

Also, Blockchain.info/wallet has a Desktop Sync feature which will keep your Bitcoin.org client's wallet.dat in sync with your Blockchain.info/wallet, and vice-versa.  That doesn't mean you still don't need to backup your wallet.dat as it [may not always sync perfectly](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=109774.0) but it does give a remote way for others to access your wallet.dat

- http://Blockchain.info/wallet