# Can I use the same seed words for two wallets?

Tags: wallet, wallet-security

I like the security of a local wallet, but at the same time I don't like the limited access. So I'm thinking I'll install the same wallet software on a second computer at my office and use the same seed words. This should get me access to the same private keys both at home and the office. I'll be the only person using the wallets, so accidental double sending won't happen. I don't know if transactions created on one wallet will show on the other, however, but I don't care to much about that.

Are there any potential issues with this that I'm not seeing?

---

I'll be using Electrum and Coinomi through Bluestacks, both on Windows 7.

Comment: Related: [Can I use my wallet on different computers?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/490/can-i-use-my-wallet-on-different-computers) They advise against it, but that's from 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with how Electrum handles duplicate seeds. Personally, I start a multi-signature wallet and require only one signer but add two signers (my mobile device & my laptop). You can do this on Copay, Electrum, and most other bitcoin wallets.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Some assembly required (i.e. I'd have to transfer by bitcoin out of my current wallets.).

Comment: Can you expand on or give a source for how to create that kind of wallet?

Comment: When creating a wallet on electrum or most wallet applications, there usually is a “multi-signature” option. Also Google can help you out quite well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me using the same seed for two wallets will result in those wallets being *duplicates* of each other.  i.e. all the coins will be spendable by either wallet.  This offers no advantage in my mind, and seems like it weakens security since there would now be two places for an attacker to get your private key.

Interesting idea to use Bluestacks to run multiple wallets.

Comment: "will result in those wallets being duplicates of each other." That's exactly the idea. Yes, a slight loss in security, but for added accessibility.

Comment: Coinomi is an android only wallet (but I don't want coin on my phone), but can hold all the alt coins I have/want, side by side. But their source is private, so they have less trust. That's where electrum comes in.